# Idioms indicating symbiosis rather than conflict

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

In order to explain a situation in which it's better to compromise and set differences aside, I'm looking for an idiom.

In fact, I want to say, despite the huge and critical differences and problems (between two parties/things), **it's better to select a symbiosis that helps both parties to take benefits of each others.**

If it helps, the problem between them could not be settled in the early future and the context is technological.

Comment: Not worth an answer, but: if I recall my school biology correctly, symbiosis requires "intimate cellular contact"; there is another term, "commensalism" (from commensal, eating at the same table) for mutual benefit that is not symbiotic. It's not appropriate for the case you describe, though. Other idioms? "win-win" perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- [Put aside (our) differences](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+aside+differences)

> forget about or put aside the things that one argues about, disagrees with, or dislikes about the other side, usually in order to achieve a common goal

- [Look past (our) differences](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/look+past+something)

> To ignore, disregard, or forgive something; to overlook something.

Consider also the concept of [constructive ambiguity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_ambiguity) which may be relevant but not directly applicable:

> deliberate use of ambiguous language on a sensitive issue in order to advance some political purpose

Specifically:

> further hopes that the ensuing postponement of resolution on this particular point, in a way that causes neither side excessive discomfort, will enable them to make real progress on other matters

Answer (score 1):

[Paul Hoffman, writing for the Daily Maverick {March 2022}](https://www.dailymaverick.co.za/opinionista/2022-03-13-jaw-jaw-is-better-than-war-war-and-there-is-only-a-small-window-of-opportunity-for-talk-in-ukraine/), addresses what he sees as the need for a negotiated peace in the Ukraine:

> The sooner the mediation route is explored between Russia and Ukraine
> the better for all parties. The zero-sum game of a scorched earth
> policy (such as that used by the British against the Boers in the
> Second South African War) does not belong in the 21st century. ...
>
> Sir Winston Churchill, wartime British leader, who had plenty of
> experience of talking and of fighting, is credited with originating
> the phrase “**Jaw-jaw is better than war-war**”.

The adage is famous, but Churchill's actual words were apparently @Churchill actually said, 'Meeting jaw to jaw is better than war."

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if they have to ["learn to live with each other"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/learn+to+live+with). (This is fairly close to the etymological roots of "symbiosis".)

Comment: Very good suggestion and candidate to be accepted!

Answer (score 0):

A phrase that's often used in this sort of context is

**a win-win solution**

Oxford Languages:

> adjective
>
> of or denoting a situation in which each party benefits in some way. "we are aiming for a win-win situation"